# Cargar un archivo .txt con <input type="file" ... >

Tags: javascript

Uso la etiqueta input de html y pongo la clase "file". Edito esta función en javascript:

```
function LoadFile(){
var  text = document.getElementById("inputFile").value;
console.log(text); //"C:\fakepath\exito.txt"

}
```

y aquí va mi html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>save file button and script</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
<body>
<h1>Load File on a Root  </h1>
  <p>Load File</p>
   <input type="file" name="new-image" id="inputFile">
  <button id="loadFile" type="button" onclick="LoadFile()">Load File</button>
   <p>Texto para editar </p>  
  <textarea id="textArea" rows="4" cols="30" style="width:300px;height:600px"></textarea> 
 <script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.9/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es cargar el texto que tengo en un .txt llamado "exito.txt".
pensaba que lo iba a poder hacer con el método document.getElementById("inputFile") pero no sé de que atributo cogerlo, si hago .value me da una ruta, que debe ser temporal porque C:\fakepath\exito.txt no es la ruta donde tenía el archivo llamado "éxito".
Mi pregunta es **¿Que campo he de poner en documentgetElement ... para que pueda transferir ese valor mediante una operación de asignación a la viariable text?**

Answer (score 2):

Los input de tipo file tienen un campo especial llamado `files` de donde puedes obtener los datos de los ficheros. Pero no es tan sencillo como simplemente leer ese dato, necesitas un FileReader para procesar el objeto File:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('file');
const editor = document.getElementById('contenido');
input.addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (input.files.length > 0) {
    readFile(input.files[0]);
  }
});

function readFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    editor.value= reader.result; 
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="contenido" rows="4" cols="30" style="width:500px;height:300px"></textarea> 

<input type="file" id="file"/>
```